# Problems overloading the << Operator

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, operator-overloading

I am trying to overload the << operator for my Currency class but I get this compiler error:  `C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '&'`

In my .h file I have:

```
 friend ostream &operator << (ostream &, const Currency&);
```

And in my Currency.cpp file I have:

```
    ostream &operator << (ostream &stream, const Currency &obj){
      stream<<"$"<<obj.dollars<<"."<<obj.cents;
      return stream;
      }
```

Everything up until now worked fine, but choked once I put that in:

I have the following at the top of my .h file:

```
    #ifndef CURRENCY_H
    #define CURRENCY_H

  #include<iostream>
  #include<string>
  #include<ostream>
  #include<sstream>

  class Currency; //forward delcaration

  //Function prototypes for overloaded stream operators
  ostream &operator << (ostream &, const Currency &);
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong.  Help would be great.  Thanks

Comment: It pointed to the line where the functions were...it's resolved...it was a missing namespace.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ostream` is declared in `namespace std` and you are missing `std::` identifier before it:

```
std::ostream &operator << (std::ostream &, const Currency &);
```

If you want to avoid `std::` then after header file you can put `using namespace` statement:

```
...
#include<ostream>
using namespace std;  // this is not desirable though in real world programming

ostream &operator << (ostream &, const Currency &);
```

**Edit:** `using namespace <>` is not recommended in real world programming at the file top. I have put that part just for FYI.

Comment: Yeah, I just realized what I forgot in the head...you are correct but in the head I put `using namespace std` and that solved the issue like the example in the book.  I'll accept this answer in 5 minutes

Comment: I upvoted you before seeing the part about adding the `using` statement, and now I wish I hadn't! Really? You're advocating adding `using namespace std;` to a header file at file scope??

Comment: @Praetorian, no I don't advocate it at all. Since this is homework, I stated that. I will edit that part.

Comment: @Praetorian you can remove the upvote.  I am not sure about the disadvantages of doing `using namespace std;` as I am still in intro to CS and that is what our books/professor use.

Comment: @TravisPessetto I haven't removed the upvote because he did answer your question. The disadvantage of having `using namespace std;` in a header is that that declaration applies to every file that includes your header. So all translation units including it will have the contents of the std namespace visible in the global namespace, and since the std library defines functions with very commonly used names (std::find for instance) there are more chances of introducing name collisions.